# Script Cant Register FileWatcher As Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell, windows-7, scheduled-tasks, filesystemwatcher

I have the below script which monitors a file. When the file is changed, a new text file is created at another location.

I need to run this as a scheduled task when the user logs into the machine.

When I run this script manually it works perfectly - the event is registered and I can test it by modifying the `logonalert.txt` file, and I can see that a new file is created in `C:\test\filewatching\logons` with the current time as the filename.

However, when I set this to run as a scheduled task (triggered when a user logs into the machine), the event doesn't register.

The script is definitely running, becuase I can see both message boxes, but the event does not register!

I have been checking event registration by testing the trigger defined in the script as well as running `Get-EventSubscriber`.

**The Script:**

```
# Load Forms
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$username = $env:USERNAME

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($username)

# The action to run when a file is changed 
$action = {
    New-Item C:\test\filewatching\logons -Name "$(Get-Date -Format HHmmss).txt" -ItemType File
 }

function Register-Event {
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "\\file\home$\$username\Application Data"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    $watcher.Filter = "logonalert.txt"
    $changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
}

Register-Event

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Done.")
```

**Scheduled Task**

My action is set up like this:

- Program/script

  - PowerShell
- Add Arguments

  - "\file\Administration\Unused\FileWatcher\FileWatcher.ps1"

The script definitely runs like this (as I can see both messageboxes), but there is no registered event.

I am running the scheduled task as the current user, which should work, because running it manually works just fine (unless there is something I am missing here). I also noticed that calling the script from a `.BAT` file has the same effect (Ie, I can see the messageboxes, but no event is subscribed to...)

Does anyone know of any reason why the event registration script might work when running it manually, but fails when it is run as a scheduled task?

Comment: How have you set up the 'Action' in the Scheduled Task? And are you running the task under an account the has admin permissions?

Comment: @Richard Hi Richard I updated my answer

Comment: Does the script stay running in task scheduler? As I seem to remember that events subscribed to using `Register-ObjectEvent` only last the duration of the script.

Comment: @Richard the scheduler seems to think the script is still running, but it is hard to say as this doesn't always seem to be right - I have found another solution for this problem though so may post that as the answer here

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: @MarkDeven I think I ended up doing something with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838357/how-to-debug-register-a-permanent-wmi-event-which-runs-a-script-on-file-creation/36886123#36886123